# To ensure uniqueness of parent record(s)

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I ensure that I am getting uniqueness on the parent record?  I am wanting to get a count of mopid + user on a day by day count. How can I do this?  Here is my code so far, I just have low confidence that it isn't giving me uniqueness on a mopid + user + day.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') DayWorked, MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER, MOPNOTES.mopid, COUNT(*) AS DAILY 
FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY 
INNER JOIN MOPUSER.MOPNOTES 
  ON MOPACTIVITY.MOPID=MOPNOTES.MOPID
WHERE MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEDATE > TO_DATE('01-JUL-13', 'DD-MON-YY') AND MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEDATE< TO_DATE('01-AUG-13', 'DD-MON-YY')
AND MOPACTIVITY.MOPSERVICEIMPACTED <> 'VOICE'
AND MOPACTIVITY.MOPSERVICEIMPACTED <> 'PWR/ENV'
AND (MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Ramesh%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Saravanan%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Boominathan%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Srinivasan%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Sathya%')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER,MOPNOTES.MOPID
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER,MOPNOTES.MOPID
```

Comment: The mopid is the unique record of the parent table, and also in the child records but not unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, GROUP BY will give you unique rows per combination of columns grouped by.  Since you are grouping by mopid + user + day, you will have uniqueness on mopid + user + day.

To illustrate, this query:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM ( SELECT MOD(LEVEL, 2) a, MOD(LEVEL, 4) b FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 11 )
GROUP BY a, b
```

... will give you the same results as this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b
FROM ( SELECT MOD(LEVEL, 2) a, MOD(LEVEL, 4) b FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 11 )
```

If you really want to be sure, you could verify that the counts match between the following two queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
SELECT TO_CHAR(MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') DayWorked, MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER, MOPNOTES.mopid, COUNT(*) AS DAILY 
    FROM ...[etc]...
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER,MOPNOTES.MOPID
    --ORDER BY TO_CHAR(MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER,MOPNOTES.MOPID
)

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ROWNUM, TO_CHAR(MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') DayWorked, MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER, MOPNOTES.mopid --, COUNT(*) AS DAILY 
    FROM ...[etc]...
    --GROUP BY TO_CHAR(MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER,MOPNOTES.MOPID
    --ORDER BY TO_CHAR(MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER,MOPNOTES.MOPID
)
```